# How can I display the word "Comment" if a number is 1 and "Comments" otherwise using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, if-statement

I'm using Facebook Comments with only access to HTML. No server side scripting.

My default output is "# Comments".

```
<a class="comments" href="URL"><div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="URL"></div> Comments</a>
```

How can I use Javascript to make "Comments" turn into "Comment" if the number of comments in 1?

Thank you for your help!

Edit:

I'm using the standard Facebook Comments tag: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

The outputted HTML is:

```
 <a class="comments" href="URL"><div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="URL" fb-xfbml-state="rendered"><span class="fb_comments_count">4</span></div> Comments - Click to Add Yours</a>
```

I'd like to just say "Comments" if it's 0, or anything above 1. And Comment if it's 1.

Comment: Where is the part you store the number?

Comment: what is the html structure when you have comments (and when you have multiple comments)..based on the change, count the repetitive html element and make your text accordingly.. (perhaps your details are too low)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use jQuery.length to count how many instances of the comments class exist and then if the number is 1 you could use jQuery.HTML to change the content of the div

so...

```
var commentCount =  $('.FBcomment').length();

if(commentCount == 1){

 $('.comments').html('Comment');//would be more efficient to have an id here rather than a class

 }
```

Comment: This is untested by the way, just threw it together

Answer (score 0):

```
function commentText(numberOfComments){
 return "comment" +((numberOfComments > 1 )?"s":"");

}
```

use the Facebook JS SDK to find number of comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function comment_text( num_comments ){
    return 'comment'+ ( num_comments === 1 ? '' : 's' );
}
```

like so:

```
var comment_count = $('.fb-comments-count').text();
$(selector).text('Showing '+ comment_count + comment_text(comment_count) );
```

Note: I have changed the `num_comments > 1` to `num_comments === 1` since you would want to show *0 comments*, rather than *0 comment*

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
    <a class="comments" href="URL"><div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="URL">6</div> <span class="comment-text">Comments</span></a>        
    <a class="comments" href="URL"><div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="URL">0</div> <span class="comment-text">Comments</span></a>        
    <a class="comments" href="URL"><div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="URL">1</div> <span class="comment-text">Comments</span></a>        
    <a class="comments" href="URL"><div class="fb-comments-count" data-href="URL">3</div> <span class="comment-text">Comments</span></a>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".comments").each(function(){
            var count = parseInt($(this).find(".fb-comments-count").text());
            if( count > 1){
                $(this).find(".comment-text").text('Comments');
            }
            else if(count == 0){
            $(this).find(".comment-text").text('');
            }
            else{
                $(this).find(".comment-text").text('Comment');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer here. I really thought this would work but it appears it's showing "Comment" no matter what. I tried modifying your code but still couldn't get it.